# BCP doc,xls and jpg export are corrupted

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, bcp

Im trying to export files using BCP. Following is a example code and output from this is a corrupt file.  Appreciate your help

BCP "SELECT FILE  FROM [R3152].[dbo].[Document] with(nolock) WHERE DocumentID =1001" queryout C:\ep\1001_Lighthouse.jpg -n -T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell BinaryWriter did the magic..

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/890.export-sql-server-blob-data-with-powershell.aspx